# sp_xml_preparedocument does not recognize validated xml variable

Tags: sql-server, xml

Can anyone help I am trying to Shred an XML document into a data table in SQL Server. I am using a   XML SCHEMA COLLECTION to validate the xml document. Below is a copy of my XML Schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 targetNamespace="http://www.healthcenter.com" xmlns="http://www.healthcenter.com" 
xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema" elementFormDefault="qualified"  
version="2.0.1.1">

  <xs:element name="HealthCenter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Patients" type="PatientDetails"/>
    <xs:element name="Doctors"  type="DoctorsDetails"/>
    <xs:element name="Ailment"  type="AilementDetails"/> 
  </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="PatientDetails">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="PatientID" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="AilementID" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="DoctorID" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="DoctorsDetails">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="DoctorID" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="DoctorName" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="DoctorType" type="DoctorCategory"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 
 <xs:complexType name ="AilementDetails">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name ="AilementID" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name ="AilementName" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name ="AilementCode" type="AilmentCodeTypes"/>  
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleType name="DoctorCategory">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:enumeration value="Dentist"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="PhysioTherapist"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="Gynocologist"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="GeneralPrctitioner"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AilmentCodeTypes">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="SDE"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="SIE"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="SUE"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="NRE"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>' 

--XML Validation

DECLARE @XMLDATA XML(dbo.DoctorPatients)
DECLARE @IDOC INT
SET @XMLDATA = '<HealthCenter xmlns="http://www.healthcenter.com">
<Patients>
    <PatientID>1</PatientID>
    <FirstName>Micheal</FirstName>
    <LastName>Huie</LastName>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <AilementID>1</AilementID>
    <DoctorID>1</DoctorID>
</Patients>
<Doctors>
    <DoctorID>1</DoctorID>
    <DoctorName>Sheldon Huie</DoctorName>
    <DoctorType>Dentist</DoctorType>
</Doctors>
<Ailment>
    <AilementID>1</AilementID>
    <AilementName>Dementia</AilementName>
    <AilementCode>SDE</AilementCode>
</Ailment>  
</HealthCenter>
```

Here is how I go about shredding the data into a table using `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `OPENXML`

```
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @IDOC OUTPUT,@XMLDATA
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    OPENXML(@IDOC,'/HealthCenter/Patients',2)
    WITH(PatientID INT,
         FirstName VARCHAR(50),
         LastName VARCHAR(50),
         Age VARCHAR(3),
         AilementID INT,
         DoctorID INT
         )
      EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @IDOC
```

The above produces this error message in SQL Server

> Msg 6628, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1
>   sp_xml_preparedocument can only process untyped XML. Cast the input value to XML or to a string type.
>   Msg 8179, Level 16, State 5, Line 26
>   Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
>   Msg 6607, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_xml_removedocument, Line 1
>   sp_xml_removedocument: The value supplied for parameter number 1 is invalid.

I think I have done everything right however if someone can spot why I get such an error message would be greatful. Note I have not yet attempted to insert data into a table, just wanted to display data first.

Forgive my formatting I had to rearrange in order to get text in code blocks

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the **native** XQuery support in SQL Server 2005 and newer, rather than the clunky and memory-intensive `OpenXML` code.

Try this - does this work with your XML schema collection?

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.healthcenter.com')
SELECT
    PatientID = Patients.value('(PatientID)[1]', 'int') ,
    PatientFirstName = Patients.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ,
    PatientLastName = Patients.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ,
    PatientAge = Patients.value('(Age)[1]', 'int') ,
    PatientAilmentID = Patients.value('(AilementID)[1]', 'int') ,
    PatientDoctorID = Patients.value('(DoctorID)[1]', 'int') 
FROM
    @XmlData.nodes('/HealthCenter/Patients') AS XTbl(Patients)
```

Comment: Seems to be a nice answer but I dont understand it, is it a CTE that you have built, please explain the from clause, the @XmlData variable was not declared and I am also not sure if this code is being validated by the xml Schema?

Comment: Seems to be a nice answer but I dont understand it, is it a CTE that you have built?

Comment: @GuruNot: no, it's not a CTE - it just uses the `WITH XMLNAMESPACE` "prefix" to specify the XML namespace to use for the following statement, so that you don't have to specify that XML namespace inside each and every call to `.value()` to get the values of the individual XML elements